# A non-negative local submartingale of the class DL is a submartingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

Can somebody explain why a non-negative local submartingale of the class DL is a submartingale? I was reading the proof here https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/local-martingales/ in Lemmma  3 but I dont understandd why can we take the limits inside the cconditional expectation usingg the uniform integrrability property!

Comment: Most people will be to lazy to click on the link and search for the line where you got stuck; in order to increase the likelihoood that someone answers your question, it would be a good idea to make the question self-contained.

Comment: Thank you for the comment . I will e careful next time . Please ignore the question because I managed to understand it